# Angular2 http.get() always giving 404

Tags: json, angular, http, typescript, observable

I am trying to load a dummy json data from a file but it seems like angular2 http.get method does not able to pick that up. Every time it is giving resource not available with a 404 status. I am using the below code.

```
const obs: Observable<any> = this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/mock-json/cashback.json')
    .map((res: Response) => {
      console.log('***********',res.json());
      res.json(); })
    .do((res) => this.loadedCB = res);
 if (this.loadedCB) {
     return Observable.of(this.loadedCB);
 }
```

Even when I try the URL http://localhost:4200/assets/mock-json/cashback.json manually in browser it works. Can't figure out why it is not working with http.get().

Comment: Try to remove the domain just like `/assets/mock-json/cashback.json`

Comment: Is your angular app running on the same port (:4200) like the backend?

Comment: In the dev tools, do you see the request?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might to happen because you are never subscribing to the observable so that it may start it's execution, and thus you won't get any result since the request is not sent (you can check that in the network tab in some web inspector).

You should try to subscribe to the observable so that it may start it's execution.

Example:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  loadedCB: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tryAndLoad();
  }

  tryAndLoad() {
    this.load().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.loadedCB = res;
      if (this.loadedCB) {
        console.log(this.loadedCB);
        return Observable.of(this.loadedCB);
      }
    });
  }

  load() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/mock-json/cashback.json')
      .map((res: Response) => {
        console.log('***********', res);
        return res.json();
      })
  }
}
```

which properly returns a result and then you can do whatever you want with the value, since you are returning an observable you can do something else (this demo does not handle that)

[image]

[image]

also add **import 'rxjs/Rx';** to the top of the page aswell so that you dont get the **this.http.get(...).map** error

Comment: I tried this and I found it in network tab of the browser as well but with status code 304 and moreover I get error message of **Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined**. Please find my code below                    `this.http.get('url')
    .map((res: Response) => {
      console.log('***********', res.json());
      res.json(); })
    .subscribe((resp: any) => {
      this.loadedCB = resp;
      if (this.loadedCB) {
        obs = Observable.of(this.loadedCB);
      }
    });` The observable variable is still undefined

Comment: @AriSan, you need to actually **return** the response as well, so: `.map((res: Response) => { console.log('***********', res.json()); return res.json(); })`